# writing returned results to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Not sure where to start, i want to write the results i return to json

current code:

```
   public Setting TestSettings(Example _example, String type)
    {
        var results = _example.GetExample("Testing");
        return results;
    }
```

Setting Model

```
string Description { get; set; }
Guid? Guid1 { get; set; }
Guid? Guid2 { get; set; }
string Key { get; set; }
string Value { get; set; }
```

GetExample

```
public Setting GetExample(string key)
        {
            using (var db = MyDataContext.StoredProcs)
            {
                return db.GetExample<Setting>(key, _curGuid1, _curGuid2, SettingExtensions.SettingFactory());
            }
    }
```

Comment: JSON.[De]Serialize is what you want?

Comment: Is it a WCF service? a pure c# method? what is your context?

Comment: @SteveB the type of return is: Description: name, Id: 232, Guid1: someGuide, Guid2: other Guide, Key: accessType, Value: enter" - pure c#

Comment: @SteveB it's tagged as asp.net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
 var resultslist = _example.GetExample("Testing");

 var result = new DataSourceResult()
 {
    Data = resultslist 
 };
 return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: what name space is DataSourceResult() under?